# not able to accessing the $scope value using angular-modal-service

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular-modal-service to create modals. i am using angular ui-router.

### controller:

```
$scope.leave = leaveData;
ModalService.showModal({
  templateUrl: "exampletemplate.html",
  controller: "SampleController"      
});
```

I am not able to getting the $scope value inside template(`ng-repeat=leavedata in leave`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because modal has a separate scope. If you want to access any data within modal then define them inside the controller assigned to the modal. In your scenario it is "SampleController" or you can pass data using inputs field of the modal options.

```
ModalService.showModal({
  templateUrl: "exampletemplate.html",
  controller: "ExampleController",
  inputs: {
    name: "Fry",
    year: 3001
  }
})
```

https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service